# How can I integrate $ \int df (x) \ dx ?$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I had a lesson in statics of the beam (engineering) where we related the moment $ M (x) $ with the shear stress $ T (x) $ and the moment distribution $ m (x) $, finding the equation:
$$ d M (x) = T (x) dx-m (x) dx -d T (x) dx,
$$
which we solved by neglecting the term $ dT (x) dx $ as follows
$$ M (x) = \int (T (x) + m (x)) dx + c_1.
$$
I was wondering how it was possible to express $ M (x) $ in terms of $ T (x) $ and $ m (x) $ without simplifying, that is, how to approach analytically an integral of the kind $ \int df (x) dx ?$

This expression and its notation derive from the fact that $ f (x) + df (x) $ means "the value of $ f $ at the point $ x $ plus a certain increment of it", as it was presented to me in class.

Comment: What does $df\,dx$ mean to you in an integral? Do you mean just $df$?

Comment: The notation seems wierd to me

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi   This expression and its notation derive from the fact that $ f (x) + df (x) $ means "the value of $ f $ at the point $ x $ plus a certain increment of it", as it was presented to me in class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the $d$'s in this discussion represent infinitesimal changes, not formal mathematics. Then the term
$dT(x)dx$ is the product of two infinitesimals and so should be neglected. If you were working formally, it would vanish in some correct limiting argument, so there is no need or reason to try to solve the differential equation for $M$ that includes that term.

Comment: in engineering I often find similar equations where a term is canceled because "higher order", in general, if I find the product of two infinitesimals, can I always neglect it?

Comment: Of course not. E.g. consider double and triple integrals.

Comment: @RafaBudría Nothing in my answer speaks about double integrals. Of course there you have double sums over infinitesimal areas, which are  often the product of infinitesimal lengths.

Comment: @PatrickDanzi You can neglect the second order effects if you understand the expression well enough to know that it's a correct description of the phenomenon you're modeling. Whether that's "always" depends on your understanding.

Comment: @EthanBolker "always" maybe means "sometimes" sometimes and I didn't notice it. I am sorry. There are product of infinitesimals beyond the examples I mentioned., as in the squared line element. The higher degree terms in the differentials disappear naturally when treated properly, using limits.